# Performing Google Search using Python code

Tags: python, search

I'm trying to perform a Google search in Python.

Here is the code:

```py
# install lib beautifulsoup4
# install lib google
try:
    from googlesearch import search
except ImportError:
    print("No module named 'google' found")

# to search 
query = input('Search: ')

for j in search(query, tld='com', lang='en', num=10, start=0, stop=None, pause=1.0): 
    print(j)
```

At first it worked well, but after a few more times this error pops up and closes my terminal instantly: 
[image]

Comment: Hi..We encourage you to get involved in the community, but please don’t thank in the question. It eventually degrades the quality of the site. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`429: Too Many Requests` indicates that you have made a lot of requests in a given period of time. For protection against [dDoS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) and [bots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_bot). So it won't allow you to send a lot of requests in a small period of time.

To work around that, you can explore the following.

1) Incorporate and rotate [`user agents`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent).

2) Use and rotate proxies.